# javascript nested callback-functions return

Tags: javascript, function, callback, cordova, return

how can i return the value evt.target.result from this function?
or is there a way which is better?

Thanks a lot

```
function datei_lesen(datei){
    fileSystem.root.getFile(datei, null, function(fileEntry){

         fileEntry.file(function(file){

            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
                return evt.target.result;         
            };
            reader.readAsText(file);

        }, function (evt) {
    alert("2:"+evt.target.error.code);
    });
    }, function (evt) {
    alert("1:"+evt.target.error.code);
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No ideas here?

otherwise i have to use global variables